To Show Striped Row Tags when filtering using a entry in tkinter
I want that my Treeview shows Striped Row Tags when filtering using a entry in tkinter. The code works fine before filter, the filter function also works fine but it does not shows the Striped Row Tags. somebody could help to solve it. I assume based on the level of knowledge of Python and tkinter the must be useless code there. Here is the code:
The problem is the def execute_search(event) function:
#import modules 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#Load data
Data = [
        ["John", "Elder", 1, "3223 NE 36Th", "Fort Lauderdale", "Florida", "33308"], 
        ["Johny", "Elder", 2, "3223 NE 36Th", "Fort Lauderdale", "Florida", "33308"],
        ["Joe", "Elder", 3, "3223 NE 36Th", "Fort Lauderdale", "Florida", "33308"],
        ["marty", "Elder", 4, "3223 NE 36Th", "Fort Lauderdale", "Florida", "33308"],
        ["don", "Elder", 5, "3223 NE 36Th", "Fort Lauderdale", "Florida", "33308"],
        ["mike", "Elder", 6, "3223 NE 36Th", "Fort Lauderdale", "Florida", "33308"],
        ["Paula", "Elder", 7, "3223 NE 36Th", "Fort Lauderdale", "Florida", "33308"],
        ["Vianney", "Elder", 8, "3223 NE 36Th", "Fort Lauderdale", "Florida", "33308"],
        ["Mariana", "Elder", 9, "3223 NE 36Th", "Fort Lauderdale", "Florida", "33308"],
        ["Ignacio", "Elder", 10, "3223 NE 36Th", "Fort Lauderdale", "Florida", "33308"],
        ["Paul", "Elder", 11, "3223 NE 36Th", "Fort Lauderdale", "Florida", "33308"],
        ["Pablo", "Elder", 12, "3223 NE 36Th", "Fort Lauderdale", "Florida", "33308"],
        ["Pedro", "Elder", 13, "3223 NE 36Th", "Fort Lauderdale", "Florida", "33308"],
        ["Pascal", "Elder", 14, "3223 NE 36Th", "Fort Lauderdale", "Florida", "33308"],
        ["Peter", "Elder", 15, "3223 NE 36Th", "Fort Lauderdale", "Florida", "33308"],
       ]

#create a window
root = Tk()

root.title('Users List')
#root.iconbitmap()
root.geometry("1000x500")

#Add some style
style = ttk.Style()

#Pick a Theme
style.theme_use('default')

#Configure the Treeview color
style.configure("Treeview", 
                bakground="#D3D3D3",
                FOREGROUND="black",
                rowheight=25,
                fieldbackground="#D3D3D3")

#Change selected color
style.map('Treeview', 
          bakground=[('selected', "#D347083")])

#Create the Treeview Frame
tree_frame = Frame(root)
tree_frame.pack(pady=10)

#Create the Treeview Scrollbar
tree_scroll = Scrollbar(tree_frame)
tree_scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

#Create the Treeview
my_tree = ttk.Treeview(tree_frame, yscrollcommand=tree_scroll.set, selectmode="extended")
my_tree.pack()

#Configure Scrollbar
tree_scroll.config(command=my_tree.yview)

#Defining Columns
my_tree['columns'] = ("First Name", "Last Name", "ID", "Address", "City", "State", "Zipcode")

#Formating our columns
my_tree.column("#0", width=0, stretch=NO)
my_tree.column("First Name", anchor=W, width=140)
my_tree.column("Last Name", anchor=W, width=140)
my_tree.column("ID", anchor=CENTER, width=100)
my_tree.column("Address", anchor=CENTER, width=140)
my_tree.column("City", anchor=CENTER, width=140)
my_tree.column("State", anchor=CENTER, width=140)
my_tree.column("Zipcode", anchor=CENTER, width=140)

#Creating headings
my_tree.heading("#0", text="", anchor=W)
my_tree.heading("First Name", text="First Name", anchor=W)
my_tree.heading("Last Name", text="Last Name", anchor=W)
my_tree.heading("ID", text="ID", anchor=CENTER)
my_tree.heading("Address", text="Address", anchor=CENTER)
my_tree.heading("City", text="City", anchor=CENTER)
my_tree.heading("State", text="State", anchor=CENTER)
my_tree.heading("Zipcode", text="Zipcode", anchor=CENTER)

#Add our data to the screen
global count
count = 0


for record in Data:
       if count % 2 == 0:
            my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text='', values=(record[0], 
            record[1], record[2], record[3], record[4], record[5], record[6]), tags= 
            ('evenrow',))
       else:    
            my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text='', values=(record[0], 
            record[1], record[2], record[3], record[4], record[5], record[6]), tags= 
            ('oddrow',))
            #increment counter
            count +=1
            #print(record)


#create a frame
data_frame = LabelFrame(root, text="Record")
data_frame.pack(fill="x", expand="yes", padx=20)

#create the entry
fn_label = Label(data_frame, text="First Name")
fn_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10)
fn_entry = Entry(data_frame)
fn_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)

#function to filter data
def execute_search(event):

       global count
       count = 0 

       query = fn_entry.get().lower()
       print(query)
       for item in my_tree.get_children():
              my_tree.delete(item)

       data_list = []
       for item in Data:
              if query in item[0].lower():
                     my_tree.insert("", "end", values=item)
              for item in Data:
                     data_list.append(item)
                
#Create straped row tags
my_tree.tag_configure('oddrow', background="white")
my_tree.tag_configure('evenrow', background="lightblue")


#Not in use
def query_database():

        global count
        count = 0    

        for record in Data:
                if count % 2 == 0:
                        my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text='', values= 
                        (record[0], record[1], record[2], record[3], record[4], record[5], 
                        record[6]), tags=('evenrow',))
                else:    
                        my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text='', values= 
                        (record[0], 
                        record[1], record[2], record[3], record[4], record[5], record[6]), 
                        tags=('oddrow',))
                        #increment counter
                        count +=1
                        #print(record)

fn_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', execute_search)


root.mainloop()


You didn't specify the tag option when inserting data inside execute_search().
Updated execute_search() to fix the issue:
def execute_search(event):
    global count
    count = 0

    my_tree.delete(*my_tree.get_children())
    query = fn_entry.get().lower()
    for item in Data:
        if query in item[0].lower():
            tag = 'evenrow' if (count%2 == 0) else 'oddrow'
            my_tree.insert("", "end", values=item, tags=(tag,))
            count += 1

Note that I have remove stuff related to data_list as it seems like it is not necessary.
